# Converting an expression to VBA in access

Tags: ms-access, vba, calc

I have created an expression to add 3 textboxes together into a 4th total box. The expression is:

```
=Cdbl(Nz[txtPart1],0)) + Cdbl(Nz[txtPart2],0)) + Cdbl(Nz[txtPart3],0))
```

I am trying to convert this into VBA code because the form I have created has so many things running on it thats why the calculation is slow. I want to be able to add an hour glass so the user doesn't think that the program is not working. I tried putting a code that sums the 3 in the after update event of all three textboxes but that did not work. Please help!

I have this code in the AfterUpdate of the 3 textboxes:

```
me.total = me.txtpPart1 + me.txtPart2 + me.txtPart3
```

Thanks

Comment: This expression is very fast, so you probably have to look elsewhere for optimization. And it _will_ work if your textboxes contain numerals, so what is your code, please?

Comment: I added the my code I have to the post

Comment: Test with your form's *Timer Interval* property set to 0.  Does that make the "4th total box" more responsive?  It seemed to in my copy of your db.

Comment: HansUp if I change the timer will that make my live clock not work?

Comment: Yes, the "Discover Time" text box will remain empty.  I'm only suggesting you test the impact of disabling the timer.  If it helps, you will need to decide what to do about "Discover Time" later.  If it doesn't help, set it back to 125 and look elsewhere for improvements.

Comment: It does help alot I will just have to not have a live clock thanks so much!

Comment: Excellent!  I think you made the right choice there, BC.  You acknowledged *"the form I have created has so many things running on it thats why the calculation is slow"*.  Updating  "Discover Time" 8 times per second only added to that workload.  And actually, I didn't see why displaying "Discover Time" at all was valuable.  Suggest you look for other opportunities to simplify that form.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you could use:

```
Me!Total.Value = 0
' Ignore error from non-numeric input.
On Error Resume Next
Me!Total.Value = CDbl(Nz(Me!txtPart1.Value, 0)) + CDbl(Nz(Me!txtPart2.Value, 0)) + CDbl(Nz(Me!txtPart3.Value, 0))
```

Comment: Ok so I should put this in the afterupdate of each of the three textboxes?

Comment: No. You would save it in a function called, say, `UpdateTotal` and then call this function from the three `AfterUpdate` events.